# Instance of FXML controller in JavaFX returns null

Tags: javafx, controller, null, fxml

I want to create a reference for the FXML Controller by this line in Class Main

```
Controller controller = (Controller) loader.getController();
```

to have access to a Controller methode from the Class GrblListener.

```
Main.controller.updateCurrentPosition(input);
```

But I always get the error

```
Exception in thread "EventThread COM5" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

What's wrong?

**Class Main:**

```
public class Main extends Application {

    public static Stage stage;
    public static Controller controller;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Scene.fxml"));
        Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();
        Controller controller = (Controller) loader.getController();

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("css/default.css").toExternalForm());

        stage.setTitle("...");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        this.stage = stage;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**Class GrblListener:**

```
class GrblListener implements SerialPortEventListener {

    @Override
    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {

        if(event.isRXCHAR() && event.getEventValue() > 0){

            try {
                String input = GrblSender.serialPort.readString();
                System.out.println(input.trim());

                Main.controller.updateCurrentPosition(input);
            }
                catch (SerialPortException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How to you connect the controller? Manually? Or in FXML?
Haven't you forgot fx:controller="Controller" in FXML?

Comment: I created the FXML with SceenBuilder, so I connect with fx:controller="package.Controller".

Comment: For now I avoid the problem by creating a public variable in the Class GrblListener which I then check with a timer every second in Class Controller to trigger the action ... Not the best solution ...

Comment: What's wrong with the solution I posted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring a local variable in `start()`, and initializing it:

```
Controller controller = (Controller) loader.getController();
```

instead of initializing the `static` variable you declared:

```
public static Controller controller ;

public void start(Stage stage) {

    controller = (Controller) loader.getController();

    // ...
}
```